# Why does this do while loop repeat infinitely?

Tags: c++, loops, std, do-while, cin

I want to prompt the user to input an integer, but if the user enters a non-integer, the program should keep demanding an integer until the user complies.

```
int getInteger(){
    int input;

    do{
        std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
        std::cin >> input;
    } while(!(std::cin));


    return input;
}
```

If the user enters an integer, the function returns it.

But if the user enters something like "Hello," the function goes on an infinite, `cout`-ing "Enter an integer: ".

How do I fix this?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/13224/ Where did you see the `while(!(std::cin))` syntax being used? `std::cin` is the the `cin` object from the `std` namespace, it doesn't return anything I think.

Comment: @Cristy Yes it does, it "returns" its state.

Comment: @Cristy: see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_not/ for information on what `!(std::cin)` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
!(std::cin)
```

will evaluate to true if `std::cin` is in a bad state, e.g. after an input operation failed. Then, all subsequent input operations will fail immediately and not change `cin`'s error state, thus the infinite loop.

To get the behavior you want, you may use something like

```
while (!(std::cin >> input)) {
    std::cout << "Try again\n";
    // Clear away the error state
    std::cin.clear();        
    // Ignore what ever garbage is still in the stream
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 
}
```

---

In the real world, you may want to handle the (generally not recoverable) failures `eof` (someone sent an End of File character) and `bad` (`cin` is broken, should not happen) different than `fail` which happens after invalid input. This is, for example, shown on [this reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) for `ignore`. However, this should not bite you in toy programs like yours seems to be.

Comment: And maybe foresee the special case of an eof on cin (e.g. redirection from a file or a pipe) to avoid endless looping ?

Comment: This code seems to work. But I am curious about @Christophe's comment. What other non-integer inputs must I watch out for?

Comment: @Username Updated my answer for that. Most likely, you need not worry at all.

Answer (score 3):

Streams convert to `true` while there is none of the failure bits is set. Once a stream entered the failure state, i.e., `std::ios_base::failbit` (or `std::ios_base::badbit`) is set for the stream, it stays in that state until the failure bit is cleared using `clear()`. In addition to clearing the stated you'd also need to get rid of the offending character(s) causing it to get into this state, e.g., using `ignore()`.